# "Syntax error in FROM clause" using OleDb in C# but no error for same query in Access itself

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access, oledbdatareader, oledbexception

When using the following SQL-statement within c#/OleDbCommand.ExecuteReader I get a syntax error in FROM-clause. 
Using exactly the same statement in MS Access directly works fine.

```
SELECT 
s.idShots, s.shotdata, c.[original], s.[hash], comp.idCompetitions, comp.competitionsname, sh.idShooters, sh.firstname, sh.lastname 
FROM (([Shots] s 
INNER JOIN [ShotsCertificate] c ON c.[uuid] = s.[uuid]) 
INNER JOIN [Competitions] comp ON comp.idCompetitions = s.fidCompetitions) 
INNER JOIN [Shooters] sh ON sh.idShooters = s.fidShooters ORDER BY s.idShots ASC
```

Within c#:

```
        OleDbCommand cmd2 = new OleDbCommand("", dbc);
        cmd2.CommandText = "SELECT s.idShots, s.shotdata, c.[original], s.[hash], comp.idCompetitions, comp.competitionsname, sh.idShooters, sh.firstname, sh.lastname FROM" +
            " (([Shots] s" +
            " INNER JOIN [ShotsCertificate] c ON c.[uuid] = s.[uuid])" +
            " INNER JOIN [Competitions] comp ON comp.idCompetitions = s.fidCompetitions)" +
            " INNER JOIN [Shooters] sh ON sh.idShooters = s.fidShooters" +
            " ORDER BY s.idShots ASC";

        log.Debug(cmd2.CommandText);
        OleDbDataReader r = cmd2.ExecuteReader();
```

The dbc connections works fine, it's used in some previous commands and everything works.

Thanks for your suggestions!

Comment: Are [Shots], [ShotsCertificate], [Competitions], and [Shooters] all tables, or is one or more of them a saved select query in Access?

Comment: Try using `As` before the alias.

Comment: all are normal tables, no views or something

Comment: @Gustav : tried with "AS" after each table, still same behaviour: works in ms access, throws an exception with executeReader

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the record, the issue was that `COMP` is included in the list of [Access SQL Reserved Words](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/248738/list-of-reserved-words-in-jet-4.0), presumably as an abbreviation of `COMPRESSION` for Access DDL. Changing the table alias from `comp` to `cmpt` allowed the query to run successfully under System.Data.OleDb:

```cs
sql = "SELECT s.idShots, s.shotdata, c.[original], s.[hash], cmpt.idCompetitions, cmpt.competitionsname, sh.idShooters, sh.firstname, sh.lastname FROM" +
    " (([Shots] s" +
    " INNER JOIN [ShotsCertificate] c ON c.[uuid] = s.[uuid])" +
    " INNER JOIN [Competitions] cmpt ON cmpt.idCompetitions = s.fidCompetitions)" +
    " INNER JOIN [Shooters] sh ON sh.idShooters = s.fidShooters" +
    " ORDER BY s.idShots ASC";
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there any way to get more precise error messages?

Answer (score 0):

I got it working ... no comment :/

```
SELECT
 [Shots].[idShots], [Shots].[shotdata], [ShotsCertificate].[original], [Shots].[hash], [Competitions].[idCompetitions], [Competitions].[competitionsname], [Shooters].[idShooters], [Shooters].[firstname], [Shooters].[lastname] 
FROM (([Shots] 
   INNER JOIN [ShotsCertificate] ON [ShotsCertificate].[uuid] = [Shots].[uuid]) 
   INNER JOIN [Competitions] ON [Competitions].[idCompetitions] = [Shots].[fidCompetitions]) 
   INNER JOIN [Shooters] ON [Shooters].[idShooters] = [Shots].[fidShooters]
ORDER BY [Shots].[idShots] ASC
```